# Passing a callback to an unnamed function within a function and getting "undefined"

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to figure out what is happening when I pass a callback to an unnamed function within a function -- for some strange reason I am getting "undefined" between function calls.

Here is a code snippet:

```
var a = function (a) {
     console.log(a);
}

var b = function(callback) {
     console.log('one');
     console.log(callback('callback - one'));
     (function(second_layer_same_callback) {
          console.log('two');
          second_layer_same_callback('callback - two');})(callback);

}

b(a);
```

Here is what I am getting

```
one 
callback - one
undefined 
two 
callback - two
```

Why do I get **undefined** ?

Comment: Because `a` doesn't `return` anything

Comment: Step 1: Format the code readably.

Comment: *"Here is what I am getting"* When? In response to what code? `b();`? In your actual code, or in the console?

Comment: For anyone who didn't know this, the return value of a function that doesn't return anything is implicitly `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get undefined ?

Your problem is this line

```
console.log(callback('callback - one'));
```

It calls your callback, which is `a`, and logs `'callback - one'` and **after that** it passes the return value of this callback, which is `undefined`, into `console.log`.

You can think of it as two steps:

```
var result = callback('callback - one'); 
console.log(result); // this is undefined because a() doesn't return anything explicitly, which is then implicitly the undefined value
```